# ubuntu 14.04.03 build android collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: android, ubuntu-14.04

/home/huangweizhou/Android5.0/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: /home/huangweizhou/buildAndroid/Android5.0/target/product/generic/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libtestercore_intermediates/modules/glshared/glsBuiltinPrecisionTests.o: file is empty
external/deqp/modules/gles31/functional/es31fBuiltinPrecisionTests.cpp:44: error: undefined reference to 'deqp::gls::BuiltinPrecisionTests::createES3BuiltinCases()'
external/deqp/modules/gles31/functional/es31fBuiltinPrecisionTests.cpp:45: error: undefined reference to 'deqp::gls::BuiltinPrecisionTests::createES31BuiltinCases()'
external/deqp/modules/gles31/functional/es31fBuiltinPrecisionTests.cpp:53: error: undefined reference to 'deqp::gls::BuiltinPrecisionTests::addBuiltinPrecisionTests(tcu::TestContext&, glu::RenderContext&, deqp::gls::BuiltinPrecisionTests::CaseFactories const&, std::vector > const&, tcu::TestCaseGroup&)'
external/deqp/modules/gles31/functional/es31fBuiltinPrecisionTests.cpp:64: error: undefined reference to 'deqp::gls::BuiltinPrecisionTests::addBuiltinPrecisionTests(tcu::TestContext&, glu::RenderContext&, deqp::gls::BuiltinPrecisionTests::CaseFactories const&, std::vector > const&, tcu::TestCaseGroup&)'
external/deqp/modules/gles3/functional/es3fBuiltinPrecisionTests.cpp:44: error: undefined reference to 'deqp::gls::BuiltinPrecisionTests::createES3BuiltinCases()'
external/deqp/modules/gles3/functional/es3fBuiltinPrecisionTests.cpp:53: error: undefined reference to 'deqp::gls::BuiltinPrecisionTests::addBuiltinPrecisionTests(tcu::TestContext&, glu::RenderContext&, deqp::gls::BuiltinPrecisionTests::CaseFactories const&, std::vector > const&, tcu::TestCaseGroup&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/home/huangweizhou/buildAndroid/Android5.0/target/product/generic/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libtestercore_intermediates/LINKED/libtestercore.so] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....

make failed to build some targets (01:47 (mm:ss))